# --home or --prefix in python package install?

Tags: python, installation

When you build and install a python package, you have two choices: --home and --prefix.
I never really got the difference between the two (I always use --home) but if I understood correctly one is deprecated and the other is "the way to go"™.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: Not that I know, but I would assume that `--home` is a specialised `--prefix` that is your home directory. If this is true, and one of them is deprecated, it'd be `--home`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation) documentation, the "standard" way is to specify neither, and to let Python install it in either `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` on *nix or `C:\Python\` on Windows.

But, if you *do* decide to go for an alternate method, you can specify `--home` to name the base installation directory, typically when you want to store multiple packages in just your own directory, usually on a multi-user machine when you don't have admin access, or perhaps for just testing before a system-wide install.  `--home` is not deprecated; in fact, it was only added to Windows as of Python 2.4.

The `--prefix` option is more strange, because this lets you use one version of Python to *build* the module you're installing, while letting you *install* the module to a different location from normal.  Another example is when you have to write to a directory with one name, while reading from it with another name (some network shares are set up this way).

So the `--home` prefix specifies `home/lib/python`, `home/bin`, `home/share`, while the `--prefix` option specifies `prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/`, `prefix/bin`, `prefix/share` on *nix and `prefix/Scripts` and `prefix/Data` on Windows.